# Starcraft 2 research build

Tags: starcraft-2

So I've just started playing through the campaign on Ambitious... I mean Brutal. Is there an optimal research build given that I tend to turtle in my base?

I'm through to The Dig, and have invested in Shrike Bunkers (6 bunker slots) so far...

So what should I be focusing on with my research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weapon Speed / Armor Health -- Pick you favorite. I prefer Weapon Speed, as it becomes the better option once you consider SCVs / Medics / Science Vessels

Orbital Depots / Micro-Filtering -- if you're good about supply management, go with micro-filtering. This one is also a toss up.

Automated Refinery / Command Center Reactor -- depends on your macro ability. The Reactor becomes slightly more valuable on higher difficulties, but the Refinery enables long-distance vespene harvesting.

Raven / Science Vessel -- Pick Science Vessel for machine repair, unless you *really* like Ravens.

Tech Reactor / Tech Reactor -- No contest.

Shrike Turret / Fortified Bunker -- Fortified Bunker. The turret is basically equal to a single marine. Fortified Bunker gives it the health of +6 marines.

Planetary Fortress / Flame Turret -- depends on playstyle. Some folks like to spam planetary fortresses on the defense missions, others appreciate the flameturrets. Another tossup.

Predator / Hercules -- neither unit will see much use, firebats / hellions easily outstrip predators, and there is very little reason for drop play in the campaign. That said, the Hercules is *very* helpful on certain missions, such as the Moebius Rescue mission (exact name escapes me)

Regeneration / Bonus Energy -- The regeneration is very slow. Besides, you have SCVs / science vessels! +100 energy = longer cloaking, more yamato cannons(!), more psionic lash(!), and more healing for medic / science vessel. If you use Wraiths, Banshees, BCs, Ghosts/Spectres, Medics and/or SVs, go for the energy. The regeneration is *quite* slow.

Hive Emulator / Psi Disruptor -- Depends on playstyle. Emulator requires more micro. Both are helpful.

You can find some additional discussion [here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/Research).

Edit: Were you looking for armory purchase suggestions as well?

Comment: Not so much with the armory purchases. I know which units i use alot and not as much, and am not really likely to adapt. Cheers 8-D